# Disable "Replace in all opened documents" in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I often use Notepad++ for quick re-forming of documents (eg. replace all commas with tabs and then all dots with commas, to import some csv into my German excel). For this I use replacing. With the keyboard most times, but sometimes I accidentally use the mouse, and then I often click on *Replace All in All Opened Documents* instead of *Replace All*.

I have loads of documents opened all the time, so this regularly means that in all my files eg. all commas get replaced, which is *painful* to undo.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way to disable that button or at least make an *Are you sure?* appear?

Comment: You may have more info at https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: I do not have Facebook, Google, Twitter or Github. :-/

Comment: No needs. It's just a forum maintains by Npp developpers, you may ask for a new functionality.

Comment: For me, it doesn't give me any opportunity to register at the site, it just offers signing in with my facebook, google, twitter or github account!

Comment: then creating a dummy account will do. ( :